# Macro expansion which converts Google Logger print format(i.e. <<) to spdlog print format

Tags: glog, spdlog

I have tons of code which uses Google Logger style of log printing:
`LOG(ERROR) << "AAAA" <<< 123;`

And currently I need to replace Google logger by spdlog logger, which supports python like format:
`logger->error("{} {}", "param1", 123);`

Of course I don't want to change each log line in the code. What I am trying to do, is to rewrite `LOG(severity)` macro definition. The original macro implementation is:
`#define LOG(severity) COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_ ## severity.stream()`

Can you please recommend me how should I implement the macro? My idea was that the original arguments that were passed to LOG(ERROR) (i.e. `<< "AAAA" <<< 123`) should be printed to a string buffer, and the string buffer will be printed to the destination spdlog logger instance like this: `logger->error("{}", str_buffer.c_str());`

What is the best idea for doing this? Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct answer was posted
https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/1804